# Failed to bootstrap model: cannot start bootstrap instance

Tags: juju, maas

I’ve created a mini virtual lab where have implemented on a host a virtual environment with KVM and used virt-manager to create 2 VM for Maas and Juju. Both the VM are right and that one for Juju is in ready status on Maas.

[image]

During the bootstrap of virtual node via Juju command:

> **$:juju bootstrap maas-cloud maas-cloud-controller --to ulab-juju-controller --debug**

the result is was that:

> … juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:778 failed to bootstrap model:
>   cannot start bootstrap instance: failed to acquire node: No available
>   machine matches constraints: [(‘agent_name’,
>   [‘d6969bb2-a7f5-4666-8039-7a5655cbcc0c’]), (‘mem’, [‘3584’]), (‘name’,
>   [‘ulab-juju-controller.maas’])] (resolved to “mem=3584.0
>   name=ulab-juju-controller.maas”)

[image]

considered that I’ve already created a new cloud and adding a credential with:

> $: **juju add-cloud** and **$: juju add-credential maas-cloud**

I try to run this command without indicate the node

**> $: juju bootstrap maas-cloud maas-controller --debug**

and the result is different, the bootstrap of the node is started but another one....at this point which is the problem?

[image]
[image]

someone can help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is with the constraints imposed by the juju-controller.

Juju will connect to MAAS and try and locate a Machine that matches the minimum specifications provided.

In this case, you can see that it is looking for a machine with at least 3584MB of RAM.

Using the `to=ulab-juju-controller` constrains the query to just that node, which has 1.9GB or RAM (and is not suitable).

Without the `to=` constraint, `juju bootstrap`, juju will search, and, on failure, attempt to create a node via KVM. That explains the additional nodes.